# C# Out of Memory retrieving entity details from Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Since I have millions of records in Dynamics 365 and I need to retrieve them all, I am using paging to retrieve the entity data:

```
// Query using the paging cookie.
// Define the paging attributes.
// The number of records per page to retrieve.
int queryCount = 5000;

// Initialize the page number.
int pageNumber = 1;

// Initialize the number of records.
int recordCount = 0;

// Define the condition expression for retrieving records.
ConditionExpression pagecondition = new ConditionExpression();
pagecondition.AttributeName = "parentaccountid";
pagecondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
pagecondition.Values.Add(_parentAccountId);

// Define the order expression to retrieve the records.
OrderExpression order = new OrderExpression();
order.AttributeName = "name";
order.OrderType = OrderType.Ascending;

// Create the query expression and add condition.
QueryExpression pagequery = new QueryExpression();
pagequery.EntityName = "account";
pagequery.Criteria.AddCondition(pagecondition);
pagequery.Orders.Add(order);
pagequery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("name", "emailaddress1");                   

// Assign the pageinfo properties to the query expression.
pagequery.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
pagequery.PageInfo.Count = queryCount;
pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber = pageNumber;

// The current paging cookie. When retrieving the first page, 
// pagingCookie should be null.
pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;
Console.WriteLine("Retrieving sample account records in pages...\n");
Console.WriteLine("#\tAccount Name\t\tEmail Address"); 

while (true)
{
    // Retrieve the page.
    EntityCollection results = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(pagequery);
    if (results.Entities != null)
    {
        // Retrieve all records from the result set.
        foreach (Account acct in results.Entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.\t{1}\t{2}", ++recordCount, acct.Name,
                               acct.EMailAddress1);
        }
    }

    // Check for more records, if it returns true.
    if (results.MoreRecords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n****************\nPage number {0}\n****************", pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("#\tAccount Name\t\tEmail Address");

        // Increment the page number to retrieve the next page.
        pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber++;
        
        // Set the paging cookie to the paging cookie returned from current results.
        pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
    }
    else
    {
        // If no more records are in the result nodes, exit the loop.
        break;
    }
}
```

After a couple of hours of pulling data, the program ends saying OutofMemory exception. It would appear that memory usage grows with every new page. How does one clear the memory usage to avoid this problem?

Comment: Maybe a `GC.Collect()` helps? Looks like a .NET issue. What does your memory usage look like? You can us performance counters etc. Do you run this code stand-alone in a console app or in debug mode in Visual Studio?

Comment: It's in debug mode. It uses 150mb of ram per loop until it maxes out my ram and dies from being out of memory

Comment: 150 MB per page of 5,000 Account records? That's a lot. Could be VS is adding some overhead. Could you try running it stand alone? Maybe reducing the page size helps?

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you are retrieving only a couple columns. Getting all the columns would certainly increase memory usage.

They way that you're processing each page it would seem that the runtime  should release each `results` object after you output it to the console.
It seems that something might be causing each `results` objects to stay on the heap.

Maybe it's the reuse of the same `pagequery` object.

The only thing that looks like it persists from the `results` is the paging cookie.

`pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;`

Maybe try moving the creation of the `QueryExpression` into a method and create a new one for each page.
For example:

```
private QueryExpression getQuery(int pageNum, string pagingCookie)
{
    //all query creation code
}
```

What is going on with the condition for the `parentaccountid`? Does a single parent have millions of child accounts?

You might also want to consider tweaking the `while` loop:

```
var continue = true;
while(continue)
{
    //process
    continue = results.MoreRecords;
}
```